# UIImageView frame memory issue

Tags: iphone, uikit, memory-management

I am setting the frame property of a UIImageView at a frequency of about 30Hz. Instruments shows that QuartsCore is allocating (and releasing) 88 bytes at this frequency. The following code causes this issue.

```
CGPoint point = vectorToCircle(vec) ;
CGRect dotFrame = self.dot.frame ;

dotFrame.origin.y = (center.y - kDotHalfHeight) - point.y * kFlatRadius ;
dotFrame.origin.x = (center.x - kDotHalfWidth) + point.x * kFlatRadius ; ;

// MEMORY: this is causing allocations in QuartsCore
self.dot.frame = dotFrame ;
```

Instruments is showing a heavy net and overall ratio for allocations. I am a bit worried about memory fragmentation over time.

Is there a way to eliminate this, or do I need to rethink my design?

**Update**

I tried this on the layer and it still occurs. If I set the frame to a constant the allocations do not occur. It is only when the origin changes that 88 bytes gets allocated

**Update 2**

Using the transform property also shows that QuartsCore continuously allocates memory. The addresses for the allocations do increase, but never recycle (checking for a circular buffer space).